# Pass along calling process when specifying open-with behavior for file types and protocols on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, file-association, protocol-handler

To associate certain file types or protocols like https with a particular program it's possible to edit the registry and basically add an association that goes like this:

`"C:\MyApp.exe" "%1"`

This way the URI or file name will be passed as the first argument when calling MyApp.exe.

I was wondering if there's something else that I can add to also pass the process that's requesting the file or the resource to be opened.

I mean if there's something like this:

`"C:\MyApp.exe" "%1" "source-process"`

Answer (score 1):

The process that invoked `MyApp` is its parent process.

The application `MyApp` can get its parent by various API calls,
depending on the language it's programmed in.